# Why does "sleep 99999999 & sleep 10 & sleep 15" not sleep forever?

Tags: bash, shell, sleep

Why does the following shell command not sleep forever? I expected that the first `sleep 9999999999` is executed in the foreground and that both subsequent`sleep`'s are executed in the background.

```
sleep 9999999999 & sleep 10 & sleep 15
```

This does not seem to be the case.

How can I have the first sleep in the foreground and the other two in the background?

Comment: `&` applies to the command before it. The foreground command must be written last.

Comment: So it should be `sleep 10 & sleep 15 && sleep 9999999999`?

Comment: No wait, a double `&&` is something _completely different_ from a single `&`.

Comment: What's your **real** goal? If you want to keep the foreground process running as long as any of your background processes is active, then `a & b & wait` would make more sense.

Comment: I want a process that never stops. This is important for reasons beyond this question. In the background, I want several processes doing their jobs. I simulated this by `sleep` commands.

Comment: The goal of asking is to detect XY questions ("I want to do X, and think Y is the obvious way to do it, so am asking how to do Y instead"). If you think you need a process that never stops because you want systemd to consider your process always active (to pick one potential reason someone might *think* they want such a thing as an example), the better approach is to set it to have `Type=oneshot`, so systemd will consider the service active for dependency purposes even after its processes exited.

Comment: The reason is that Docker tool `watchtower` (see https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower) only keeps an eye out for active docker containers. So to keep my set of scripts active, I need to keep the enclosing container active, so `watchother` will restart my scripts when a new image is pushed to the registry. As of now, this `sleep infinity` approach is the best I solution I could find, but I am open for suggestions, ofcourse! I appreciate your insights.

Comment: Makes sense -- thank you for sharing that context. Personally, given that requirement, I'd be filing a feature request (or a pull request) for Watchtower.

Comment: I'm working on that pull request, but it will take some for me. I am 'hacking' the solution as discussed on this question as an intermediate solution. Thank you Charles!

Comment: `tianon/sleeping-beauty` is a lightweight executable designed for Docker that sleeps forever. Just thought you might be interested in that for some reason.

Comment: I discovered that image during my research, but it's unclear for me how to use that image, especially in combination with other scripts to be ran in the background. I also could not find example on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the background sleeps first:

```
sleep 10 & sleep 15 & sleep 9999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I think it should be:

```
sleep 9999999999; sleep 10 & sleep 15 &
```

which would sleep for 9999999999 seconds, then launch a background process to sleep for 10 seconds, then launch a background process to sleep for 15 seconds.

I think what you want though is:

```
sleep infinity
```

But, more importantly, why do you want this?

---

**Edit:** changed the command slightly 'cos of errors guys in the comments picked up

---

**Edit Edit:** In response to what you commented, I get:

```
sleep 10 & sleep 15 & sleep infinity
```

Comment: The 10 and 15 second sleeps will both start at the same time. You don't need `;` after `&`.

Comment: I want it the other way. I want to start the `sleep 10` and `sleep 15` in background immediately and I want to keep the foreground process waiting 'forever'.

Comment: `&;` is invalid syntax -- the shell won't accept it.

Comment: Note that `sleep infinity` is a GNUism. It doesn't work everywhere (not on MacOS, not on Busybox, etc). That's potentially impactful for the OP, as they're using Docker, and many common Docker containers (ie. Alpine) use busybox.